# Finding the file having keyword test.html in the folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find a file ends with the test.html in the directory using batch script
currently what I have tried so far and test.html does not exist in the folder abc

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "hastestHtml=false"
for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b "C:\\Users\\abc\\test.html"') do (
    set "hastestHtml=true"
    )
if ( !hastestHtml ) (
    echo "No test.html file found."
) else (
   echo "A test.html file was found."
   exit /b 1
    )
```

Expected output:
`No test.html file found.`

Current Output:

```
File Not Found
!hastestHtml was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: `if "%hastestHtml%" == "false" (` See `if/?` from the prompt.

Comment: Would this simple one liner work for you? ```@Dir "%UserProfile%\test.html" /A:-D /B /S 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo A test.html file was found.) || Echo No test.html file found.```

Comment: `if` doesn't work like `if TRUE command`. It's strictly `if <string1> <comparator> <string2> command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something much easier than that, use the `if` parameter

```
if exist "C:\\Users\\abc\\test.html" (echo A test.html file was found.) else (echo No test.html file found.)
```